# Thunderbird and Gmail: how to disable annoying "credentials" popups when moving

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, credentials

I maintain a number of Gmail accounts (for various purposes). I use Thunderbird downloading all e-mails to my local computer (for multiple accounts), and of course for writing e-mails. (That's via POP technology, not IMAP). I am travelling a lot across Europe, meaning, I often change the place from where I am working.

For quite a number of weeks now, when I am at a new place, Google annoys me multiple times per hour with popup windows to urge me to enter "credentials" for these accounts. I believe this is when Thunderbirds contacts the Gmail server to check for new e-mails (which I set to be done every 10 minutes or so.)

For doing this "credentials" requirement, I have to log in to my various accounts (Google accounts) via the browser and to confirm that it's me (from another place), through various steps, often including entering a number code they send my vis text message (SMS) on my mobile phone.

This is totally annoying, because I am really often moving, and it's multiple accounts. I want to be able to work from various places in Europe without Google annoying me with these specific security requirements that are based on the outdated assumption that people are mono-local.

What can I do to switch this off?

Here is a screenshot of the address line of such a popup window:

[image: Google Popups asking for credentials]

Comment: Have you enabled OAuth2, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1369790 ? That said, when I switch PC's, GMail often sends warning messages to a related account that a user has logged into the mail server from a new machine. *Perhaps* that increases security, and I just delete those superfluous, dispensable, redundant, downright pleonastic and supernumerary messages.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  - Thank you for the hint about OAuth2. It took me some time, but eventually I seem to have found a solution. The important thing was in Thunderbird account settings to not only change the "OAuth2" for "Normal password" in the *incoming server* settings but to do this also in the *outgoing server* settings. - By the way, I have no idea why this "OAuth2" was set for all the accounts. Thunderbird must have done this by itself, I guess.

Comment: Because of recent login changes by Google and others, Thunderbird 91.8 set all GMail accounts to default to OAuth2 https://www.ghacks.net/2022/04/06/thunderbird-91-8-0-makes-important-changes-to-google-mail-accounts/ . BTW, I find I have to enable cookies to get the pop-up for OAuth2 sign in; after that, cookies can be restricted.

Comment: Based on further experiments and observations: I now believe that the OAuth2 setting in Thunderbird (for outgoing and incoming connection) is principally okay, even inevitable (as Google says it will not allow the old "normal password" access any longer after May 30 2022). The issue is that one indeed has to log in once via those (for me annoying) Google popup windows to tell Google that Thunderbird is okay. - That's my current understanding. Open to further insight.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Thunderbird version 102.9.0

I had the same issue. In my case I got the popup for a GMail account I actually removed from Thunderbird. Realizing there had to be underlying code that was still call the popup I finally found I was correct.

I went into TOOLS - SETTINGS - GENERAL and scrolled to bottom of the page.
I then opened the CONFIG EDITOR and selected SHOW ALL
I scrolled down and eventually found MAIL.IDENTITY.ID entries for all accounts I had in Thunderbird, including the removed account. Each account was assigned a different ID #.
I trashed all of the entries for the ID # of the popup account.
(BTW-In my case, using the config editor's search option did not find the entries for me)